# d3.js and typescript in intelliJ: import problem

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6

Errors in browsers' console when I use **d3.select()** in typescript code. I've tried other methods like **d3-timer.now()** and had the same problem.

I'm new to typescript. 
I'm using intelliJ Ultimate 2019.1.
I've used npm to download tons of stuff so my intelliJ Project view shows node_modules to contain
    .bin
    @types
    commander
    d3
    d3-array
    ...
    d3-selection
    ...

intelliJ is showing all the javadoc-like docs in its Documentation view (after Ctrl-Q), so the types seem to be linked up nicely. :-)

// index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My title</title>
    <script>var exports = {};</script>
    <script type=module src=ts1.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>test output from me</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
// ts1.ts
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3selecter from 'd3-selection';   // Possibly rubbish?

let d:d3.Primitive = 'hello';   // Works fine! :-) Proving typescript is working
console.log(d.toString());      // Ditto. :-)

d3.select("p").style("fill", "red");           // Causes error
d3selecter.select("p").style("fill", "red");   // Causes error
```

---

```
// tsconfig.json (which I don't understand)
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

---

d3-selection doesn't help in the following file

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "T5D3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
  "d3": "^5.7.1",
    "d3-selection": "^1.4.0"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.1"
  }
}
```

the error in Firefox and Chrome console is "**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "d3". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**"
It only appears when I try to use d3.select or d3selecter.select.
I have tried putting those prefices in various places, but to no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Is the fact that you reference ts1.js in your html and you call it ts1.ts in the comment above your ts code a typo? I assume so since the ts code is working.

Have you tried adding

```html
<script src="/whereEverYoureGettingD3From"></script>
```

to your html?

Comment: No, it's not a typo. intelliJ transpiles the .ts to .js in the same folder as the .ts.
What do you mean by "/whereEverYoureGettingD3From"?

Comment: The .ts, .js and .html files are all in the same folder.

Comment: I mean like ```<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>``` or ```<script src="/yourFileDirectory/staticD3file(i.e. whatever the filename and path is)"></script>```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it changed nothing. How much typescript do you know? Surely the tsconfig and package files are doing what your suggestions is aimed to do? And as you can see, the transpiler knows d3.Primitive. And intelliJ knows more as proved by Ctrl-Q showing the doc.

Comment: I don't know much ts but I do work with d3 and js in my day job, no expert though.Currently working on a node.js/d3/electron app and if that import isn't in the html the js engine has no idea what d3 is. I would assume you're right about the primitive though.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3 addresses the same problem but didn't help me. :-(